# Load specific ZSH_THEME base on specific directory contain specific string

Tags: zsh, macos, oh-my-zsh

I'm using ***ohmyzsh***. I'm trying to load a diff [themes](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes) base on the current directory path (`pwd`)

**Logics**

If *pwd* in or contain sustring `/Sites/work/` load `af-magic`, else load `robbyrussell`.

***.zshrc***

I've tried

```
STR=$(pwd)
SUB='/Users/john/Sites/work'

if [[ "$STR" =~ .*"$SUB".* ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
  ZSH_THEME="af-magic"
else
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
fi
```

## Result

it kept loading `robbyrussell`

Ex.

[image]

Comment: You need to evaluate this every time your prompt is drawn, but right now you're only evaluating it once, at shell startup. Look at `precmd` and similar.

Comment: I thought `~/.zshrc` file loaded per Terminal tab. I opened multiple local tabs on Terminal in my Mac OS.

Comment: Are you sure we can't overwrite  `ZSH_THEME` per Terminal Tabs?

Comment: @ChrisDown `chpwd`, not `precmd`, since the change needs to be done when the current directory changes.

Comment: I thought it was going to a simple `if-check`. I guess it's harder than I was expected.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Oh, I didn't even know `chpwd` existed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the oh-my-zsh code](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/7ab15bee033a1ce6791b05f4636221cba7b9505e/oh-my-zsh.sh#L121), that `ZSH_THEME` variable is used by the oh-my-zsh initialisation code to source a per-theme file.

So if you want the theme to change whenever the current working directory lands in some directory, you need:

1. to change that variable whenever the current directory  changes
2. reproduce that same sourcing of theme files when the variable changes.

So something like:

```
load-omz-theme() {
  # copied and improved from oh-my-zsh
  if (( $# > 0 )) ZSH_THEME=$1
  if [[ -n $ZSH_THEME ]]; then
    if [[ -f $ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme ]]; then
      source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    elif [[ -f $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme ]]; then
      source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    else
      source "$ZSH/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    fi
  fi
}
adapt-theme() {
  local previous_theme=$ZSH_THEME
  case $PWD in
    ($SUB*) ZSH_THEME=af-magic;;
    (*)     ZSH_THEME=robbyrussell;;
  esac
  [[ $ZSH_THEME = $previous_theme ]] || load-omz-theme
}

chpwd_functions+=(adapt-theme)
```

BTW, `[[ "$STR" =~ .*"$SUB".* ]]` is bash syntax, not zsh syntax. In `zsh`, quoting variables in regexps doesn't disable the regexp operators in it.